# Vue: router-link not updating router-view

Tags: vue.js

I am currently working on a small website and I am at my wits end. I cannot get the navbar to work. The URL changes, but not the site itself:

App.vue

```
    <script setup>
      import Header from '@/components/AllSitesHeader.vue';
    </script>

    <template>
      <Header></Header>
      <router-view/>
    </template>

    <style>
      body{
        margin: 0;
      }

      #app {
        font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        text-align: center;
        color: #2c3e50;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      export default {
        name: "app"
      };
    </script>
```

AllSitesHeader.vue

```
    <template>
        <header>
          <nav>
            <router-link to="/" >Home</router-link> |
            <router-link to="/add">Register</router-link>
          </nav>
        </header>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default{
            name: 'AllSitesHeader',
        }
    </script>

    <style scoped>
      header {
          background-color: #006600;
          height: 150px;
      }

      nav {
        padding: 100px;
        color: aliceblue;
      }

      nav a {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
      }

      nav a.router-link-exact-active {
        color: #42b983;
      }
    </style>
```

router.js

```
    import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";

    const routes =  [
      {
        path: "/",
        alias: "/home",
        name: "home",
        component: () => import("./components/HomeView.vue")
      },
      {
        path: "/add",
        name: "add",
        component: () => import("./components/AddUser.vue")
      }
    ];

    const router = createRouter({
      history: createWebHistory(),
      routes
    });

    export default router;
```

HomeView.vue

```
        Welcome!
    </template>

    <script>
    export default{
            name: 'HomeView',
        }
    </script>
```

I tried to take all inside the Header Component and place the code directly into the App.vue file but that also didn't work. I also tried various tutorials, mostly based on this one https://www.bezkoder.com/vue-3-crud/. The app in the tutorial works, but mine doesn't. It couldn't be the way he defines the navbar, could it? Since here the navigation is much simpler: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/

Edit: Added main.js and package.json

main.js

```
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import router from './router'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import 'bootstrap'
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'


    createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "vue-3-crud",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "core-js": "^3.8.3",
        "vue": "^3.2.13"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
          "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
          "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
          "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
          "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
        },
        "rules": {}
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead",
        "not ie 11"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code.  I would check that 1) You've installed compatible versions of vue and vue-router, so please include your `package.json` file in your question. 2) You've registered the vue-router plugin, so please include your `main.js` file as well.

Answer (score 0):

@yoduh Thank you for the hint, I found my mistake, though I am still to unexperienced in vue and these technologies to fully understand why. As I mentioned, I did the tutorial from this page: https://www.bezkoder.com/vue-3-crud/

There is this one part, where I have to add bootstrap to the page (still didn't understand why, but I will look deeper into it later). There is this one line that I apparently did not do: `npm install bootstrap@4.6.0 jquery popper.js`

Yet I used bootstrap in my main.js. I was sure, I tested the page with removing the bootstrap Import but maybe I did not. Well, after I installed the missing dependencies, oh what a wonder, it worked.

Thank you again, without you I would probably have lost my mind. I still don't fully understand what was caused by what, but I guess with time and more experience (and a research what exactly all the used technologies do) I will probably understand.

I am just very happy that this prototype is now done and I can concentrate on my original task!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).